# Change jdbcAuthentication datasource when receiving a token request

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-security, datasource

I have created an Authorization Server `Spring Boot` app by using the annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer`.

I have also create a configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter
{
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);
    }
}
```

I understand that this method is executed when starting the server.

Is there a way to change this configuration depending on the request I'm sending?

E.g.

If I send `http://localhost:9000/oauth/token` I would like to use `datasource1`.

If I send `http://test.localhost:9000/oauth/token` I would like to use `datasource2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update configuration of SpringBoot application at runtime without reloading whole ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365874/how-to-update-configuration-of-springboot-application-at-runtime-without-reloadi)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html). See this article for more information. https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Another good article: http://abidhk.blogspot.com/2013/01/multiple-databases-routing-in-spring.html

Answer Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37436515/1849366